# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Tags: numpy

When loading my file i get this error: I dont see the problem.

```
hm = matplotsoccer.count(x, y, n=25, m=25) # Construct a 25x25 heatmap from x,y-coordinates
hm = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(hm,1) # blur the heatmap
matplotsoccer.heatmap(hm,cmap='Blues', figsize=20, linecolor="black", cbar=True) # plot the heatmap
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you're calling `arr.value_counts()` where `arr` is expected to be a `pandas.Series` but was a `numpy.array` instead. If this is all your code, it looks like some versioning problem is going on - try updating your libs.

Comment: Hi rafaelc, which libarries exactly